# Eclipse suddenly opens all files in fully-folded mode

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly any Java file I open in Eclipse is being opened in fully-folded mode.
I don't recall changing any settings but presumably I must have hit some special hot key or accidentally clicked someplace to ask for this behavior.

Any clues on how to turn it off?  I've tried simply disabling folding but with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding -> Initially folded elements. Uncheck "members" or hit the "Restore defaults" button.

If you have a similar problem again, try entering a term in the preferences dialog filter box on the upper left. If you enter "folding", you come quite close to the solution already.

Comment: Except that the setting there already was all of the items unchecked.